# Python: Pandas Dataframe AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

Since I am creating a dataframe, I don't understand why I am getting an array error.

```
M2 = df.groupby(['song_id', 'user_id']).rating.mean().unstack()
M2 = np.maximum(-1, (M - 3).fillna(0) / 2.)  # scale to -1..+1  (treat "0" scores as "1" scores)
M2.head(2)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Comment: What is `M` defined as?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(M - 3)` is getting interpreted as a `numpy.ndarray`.  This implies that `M` is defined somewhere as a `numpy.ndarray`.  Test it out by running:

```
print type(M)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are calling the `.fillna()` method on a numpy array. And `numpy` arrays don't have that method defined.

You can probably convert the `numpy` array to a `pandas.DataFrame` and then apply the `.fillna()` method.

Comment: Yes. I used : 
y = [np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.nan]
y_temp = pd.DataFrame(y).fillna(1E-8)[0].values

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not complete at the moment, so it is hard to pin point why `M` is causing an error. There could be a couple reasons:

1. You have a typo and `(M - 3)` should be `(M2 - 3)`

   ```
   M2 = df.groupby(['song_id', 'user_id']).rating.mean().unstack()
   M2 = np.maximum(-1, (M2 - 3).fillna(0) / 2.)  # scale to -1..+1  (treat "0" scores as "1" scores)
   M2.head(2)
   ```
2. You need to define/convert `M` as [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) somewhere else in your code

   ```
   # With out seeing this part of the code, no one can really help you
   M = pd.DataFrame(...)
   # ...
   # ...
   M2 = df.groupby(['song_id', 'user_id']).rating.mean().unstack()
   M2 = np.maximum(-1, (M - 3).fillna(0) / 2.)  # scale to -1..+1  (treat "0" scores as "1" scores)
   M2.head(2)
   ```
3. You could convert it to a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) right before you use it.

   ```
   M2 = df.groupby(['song_id', 'user_id']).rating.mean().unstack()
   M2 = np.maximum(-1, (pd.DataFrame(M) - 3).fillna(0) / 2.)  # scale to -1..+1  (treat "0" scores as "1" scores)
   M2.head(2)
   ```